# How can I get my mails from a pop-Server with php?

Tags: php, email

I am sending some mailings to a 5k list.  I am not using any mailing commerce services. As expected I am getting some mails back from my mail-deamon and I would like to delete the those from the recipient-list. Is there a way to read the pop-mails programmatically? 
is there maybe an easy and quick workaround?

Comment: This belongs on StackExchange. And the [PHP manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/extensions.membership.php) lists a number of functions from standard modules (such as the IMAP extension) that allow you to manipulate mail services, complete with code examples and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to read POP mail via PHP: [PHP: Download incoming email from POP3 or IMAP, parse it, and mark it as read/delete on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450490/php-download-incoming-email-from-pop3-or-imap-parse-it-and-mark-it-as-read-de)
(The code provided in the answer is using the functions suggested by Lèse majesté in its comment, but you find a ready to use small piece of working code thet does exacly what you need).

Obviously you will need to write also the code to programatically delete the address from your newsletter's DB.

I would use a cronjob (very easy to set on an hosting with cPanel) to programatically call the code that read the POP3 account and deletes the invalid addresses from DB.

A workaround? I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any IMAP installed on the server.  but maybe it is easier to ask the admin to do so, than searching for another solution.

Comment: @anonym-developer: an average Linux + cPanel hosting plan with emails allowing IMAP connections can cost you less than 35 bucks per year. I would try one.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set your "from" and "reply-to" address to an email address you can check? and then just check that email inbox to see what has bounced.

Comment: I thinks he's already doing this, he says he is getting some mail back. I suppose he wants to automate the process.