# POP email with Symfony2

Tags: php, email, symfony

For my Symfony2 project, I want to access to a mailbox and POP emails.
I want to treat each mail and seeks information from the header and body of the email:

- Sender Address
- Date sends email
- Subject
- Body

Has someone an idea about this?

Comment: POP mail is really inefficient compared to IMAP and has pretty much died off for that reason. Are you stuck with legacy infrastructure that dictates the use of POP3?

Comment: Yes I want to use both POP and IMAP mail

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague and off-topic but there is good documentation on sending emails in Symfony2 with the included `Swift_Mailer` bundle:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

**EDIT**

Okay, my understanding now is that you are able to send emails with Symfony2 - but you also want to be able to retrieve and process emails from Symfony2. This is really a general PHP question in my view.

You could look at PHP's IMAP suite of functions, including [`imap_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php). It should also provide some limited functionality for POP.

There are some existing related questions on SO that might help, including the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450508/312962

This assumes you have a mailbox set up already - if you are asking about setting up a POP mailbox, I would think this is outside of the scope of SO questions I'm afraid.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I know how to send email with Symfony2 and it works wery well!!

Comment: Just I want how to access to a mailbox and POP emails.

Comment: I found a solution that I will try : ZetaWebmailBundle, thank you for your help